# Entity Framework v5 release candidate throws exceptions when using enums in model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-5

I am using latest EF v5 release candidate as [per announcement here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx).
My model is using mapping files via EntityTypeConfiguration ...

When I attempted to replace string property on my model with an enum (drop+recreate db), I was getting this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The enum or spatial property 'Category' on type 'Vehicle' cannot be mapped. Use DbModelBuilderVersion 'V5_0' or later to map enum or spatial properties.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyFilter.ValidatePropertiesForModelVersion(Type type, IEnumerable`1 explicitlyMappedProperties)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.PropertyFilter.GetProperties(Type type, Boolean declaredOnly, IEnumerable`1 explicitlyMappedProperties, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapStructuralElements[TStructuralTypeConfiguration](Type type, ICollection`1 annotations, Action`2 propertyMappingAction, Boolean mapDeclaredPropertiesOnly, Func`1 structuralTypeConfiguration)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7.<MapTypes>b__1(Type type)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at WebApp.Controllers.VehiclesController.Get() in C:\WebApp\Controllers\VehiclesController.cs:line 35
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.Execute(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeActionAsync>b__0()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

I then tried decorating my MyAppDbContext with `[DbModelBuilderVersion(DbModelBuilderVersion.Latest)]` and was getting the same error...
Finnaly I tried `[DbModelBuilderVersion(DbModelBuilderVersion.V5_0)]` and I got another exception:

```
System.Data.MetadataException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(2,9) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Namespace'.
(2,41) : warning 0005: Could not find schema information for the attribute 'Alias'.
(2,54) : error 0005: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes' attribute is not declared.
(2,2) : error 0010: The element Schema in namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm was unexpected for the root element. The expected Schema in one of the following namespaces: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm, http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
       at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ToEdmItemCollection(EdmModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Db.Mapping.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.ToMetadataWorkspace(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace..ctor(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbCompiledModel..ctor(DbModel model)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbModel.Compile()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at WebApp.Controllers.VehiclesController.Get() in C:\WebApp\Controllers\VehiclesController.cs:line 35
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.Execute(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeActionAsync>b__0()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

My Controller is an ApiController and the breaking line looks like this:

```
var vehicles = _db.Vehicles.ToList();
```

BTW, I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 beta + Web API on VS 2010 (w/ .NET 4).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enums and all other new EF 5.0 features are dependent on .NET 4.5 (VS11) - both currently in Beta. If you run EF 5.0 in VS 2010 you get mostly the same functionality as in EF 4.3.1 = no enums.

Comment: do you have to have both VS11+.NET4.5 or can I use .NET 4.5 with VS2010?

Comment: @zam6ak, VS2010 projects can't target .NET 4.5